# avoid indentation through itemize

Tags: itemize

[image: 1]

I would like the avoid the indentation that I get due to itemize and stick the bullet points to the left margin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please give a minimal working example (MWE) to let us know what you've done and clarify what you want.

Comment: This question addresses the same topic:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1307